# Default registration status for on-line registrations

Tags: civievent, registration

We are trying to use CiviCRM for a registration process that has multiple levels of behind the scenes checks required which we were hoping to track by additional types of 'Registration Status' but seem to have hit a buffer in that there doesn't appear to be any way to specify the starting status for an on-line registration; am I correct in thinking you can't change this somewhere from "Registered" to something else?

We looked at the 'participant approval' option but found the full logic of that doesn't quite work for us as we need information from the corresponding price set at the point of initial submission rather than after the completion of the approval.

Comment: If you are using webform-civicrm to register you can set the registration status to whatever you require. For a nightshelter signin I use a webform with a registration status of 'Attended'

Comment: Thanks for the tip; I've resisted such 'external' dependencies in the past but perhaps it is inevitable...

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're correct that the default participant status can't be changed when using the standard event registration process. See discussion at [Default participant status doesn't recognize 'order' value of status](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-19395).

Comment: That's also helpful to know, although this wouldn't quite be want I want, as I want to set it per event rather than system-wide. ie. somewhere between this and the current ability for admins to set the participant status when registering people individually. Basically it would just be a 'default participant status' added to the on-line registration tab.